# Save Results of DBCC ShrinkFile

Tags: sql-server-2005, dbcc, scripting

When we execute the following command:

```
DBCC SHRINKFILE('MyDB_log', 1)
```

We get the following results in SSMS:

```
DBID | Field | CurrentSize | MinimumSize | UsedPages | Estimated Pages
-----|-------|-------------|-------------|-----------|----------------
 11  |   2   |    128      |   128       |  128      |     128
```

**The Question:**

How can we create a query that outputs these results to a text file, without using SSMS output window.

I have tried this:

```
CREATE TABLE #x
(
    [DBID] int,
    FileID int,
    CurrentSize int,
    MinimumSize int,
    UsedPages int,
    EstimatedPages int
)
INSERT #x 
  EXEC('DBCC SHRINKFILE(''MyDB_log'', 1)')

SELECT * 
  FROM #x

DROP TABLE #x
```

But I get the following error:

```
Msg 8920, Level 16, State 2, Line 1
Cannot perform a shrinkfile operation inside a user transaction. Terminate the transaction and reissue the statement.
```

I have also tried the following:

```
DECLARE @Statement AS VARCHAR(2000); 
SET @Statement = 'bcp "DBCC SHRINKFILE(''MyDB_log'', 1)" queryout C:\Test.txt -c -UDBAdmin -P1234 -S192.168.123.123';

exec xp_cmdshell @Statement
```

I get:

```
Error = [Microsoft][SQL Native Client]BCP host-files must contain at least one column
```

Comment: Side note: I don't wanna point the finger, but why in the world would you wanna script the log file shrinking? It's not an action that should be automated, as I think of its purpose.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way I see it is a batch file using sqlcmd:

```
sqlcmd -S .\SQL2008R2 -E -Q "dbcc loginfo" >> log.txt
```

The redirect operator appends data at the end of the file.

-Q parameter was used for closing the sqlcmd session immediately.

Answer (score 1):

You can output the query results to file by pressing Ctrl+Shift+F if you're looking at one-off query.

If you're looking for something you can automate you can wrap the query in Powershell or another scripting language and have that write the file.

Comment: I am trying to script this, as I don't want to login to the Database Server every time I want to execute this. I'm hoping the scripting can be done in SSMS.

Comment: Okay.  Wrap it in Powershell.  You can use invoke-sqlcmd and then use Powershell to create the file.  If you're more comfortable with VBScript or another language (or even SSIS) that can be used too.

Answer (score 0):

There are two options that are simple enough: either use a Linked Server or SQLCLR.

**Linked Server**

This option requires three things:

1. that the `'remote proc transaction promotion'` property of the Linked Server be set to `false`, which prevents SQL Server from trying to use MSDTC to tie the local and remote actions together into a single transaction.
2. that the `'rpc out'` property of the Linked Server to `true` so that the result set returned by `DBCC` can be passed back to the local context.
3. and that you use the Linked Server via `EXEC('DBCC...') AT [LinkedServerName];`

For a working example of this approach, please see my answer (also here on DBA.SE) to:

[How can I save the results of DBCC SHRINKFILE into a table?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/162084/how-can-i-save-the-results-of-dbcc-shrinkfile-into-a-table/162107#162107)

**SQLCLR**

Using a regular / external connection (i.e. not the Context Connection) that has the `Enlist` connection string keyword set to `false`, you can create either a SQLCLR Stored Procedure or Scalar Function / UDF. Just like with the Linked Server with `'remote proc transaction promotion'` disabled, the new connection with `Enlist = false;` will not attempt to bind the local and remote transactions together.

While a UDF does lend itself more to being used in set-based operations, the simplest approach (I believe, but have not tested) would be to create a Stored Procedure wherein you pass `SqlCommand.ExecuteReader()` (where the `SqlCommand` object is the call to `DBCC`) into `SqlContext.Pipe.Send()`.